# Issue in comparing NSString inside NSMutable Array

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

i write a method that loops through an array of buttons and checks if a string is equal to any of the buttons titles inside the array, but it doesn't work although the string passed to that method equals some strings inside the array, here's my code:

```
-(void)checkDuplicatesInSection:(NSString*)btnLabel
{
    for (UIButton* btn in self.test) {
        if([btnLabel isEqualToString:btn.titleLabel.text])
        {
            NSLog(@"Inside check Dublicates--->Title Existed");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Inside check Dublicates--->Title Not Existed");
        }
    }
}

// self.test---> it's an array contains group of buttons
// btnLabel----> it's a string passed to that method
```

What I don't understand is why when I run the program, I get both `Inside check Dublicates--->Title Existed` and `"Inside check Dublicates--->Title Not Existed`.

Comment: This question is confusing.  I cleaned up the formatting, but could you restate or elaborate on your problem?

Comment: if([btnLabel isEqualToString:btn.titleLabel.text])
that statement doesn't work right, although i print the buttons titles and the array is working properly, when i remove btn.titleLabel.text and put a constant string, it works!!

Comment: Could you log out your `self.test` array? One of the pointers might not be a `UIButton`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code:

```
if([btnLabel isEqualToString:btn.titleLabel.text])
{
    NSLog(@"Inside check Dublicates--->Title Existed");
} else {
    NSLog(@"Inside check Dublicates--->Title Not Existed");
}
```

will be executed multiple times because it is in a `for` loop. That's why you get both logs printed when you run your code.

To test whether `self.test` contains the string `btn.titleLabel.text` you should modify your code into:

```
-(void)checkDuplicatesInSection:(NSString*)btnLabel
{
    BOOL found = NO;
    for (UIButton* btn in self.test) {
        if([btnLabel isEqualToString:btn.titleLabel.text]) {
            found = YES;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (found) {
        NSLog(@"Inside check Dublicates--->Title Existed");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Inside check Dublicates--->Title Not Existed");
    }
}
```

Or you can simply use the method [`-containsObject:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-BABCEJDI) <sup>*</sup>:

```
    -(void)checkDuplicatesInSection:(NSString*)btnLabel
{
    BOOL found = [self.test containsObject:btn.titleLabel.text];

    if (found) {
        NSLog(@"Inside check Dublicates--->Title Existed");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Inside check Dublicates--->Title Not Existed");
    }
}
```

---

<sub><sup>*</sup> This will work even if `btn.titleLabel.text` is an `NSString`.</sub>